# How to use a varibale or dependency injection into a each method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function show(Project $project)
    {                
        $client = $project->client;
        $users = $project->projectUsers();  
        $user_project = UserProject::where('user_id', $users[0]->id)
            ->where('project_id', $project->id)
            ->first()->id;       
        $users->each(function ( $user ){
            // $user->total_hours = $user->with('usersHoursPerProject');           
            $user->total_hours = $user->usersHoursPerProject($user_project);
        });        

        return Inertia::render('Projects/show', [
            'client' => $client,
            'users' => $users,
            'project' => $project
        ]);
    }
```

i need to use user_project into the each function
i try to use the keyword global but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an anonymous function in PHP you need to tell it which variables from surrounding scopes. The use of `use` is correct in this case too :

```
$users->each(function ($user) use($user_project){
    // $user->total_hours = $user->with('usersHoursPerProject');           
    user->total_hours = $user->usersHoursPerProject($user_project);
});
```

See the official documentation of [Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) <sub><sup>(Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope)</sup></sub>

Comment: thank you so much, it was really useful :D